# Storybook: Does not document Angular components (No code available)

Tags: angular, storybook, monorepo, angular-storybook, storybook-addon

I have a Nx, Strorybook with Angular set up.
The **Storybook docs** does not documenting my angular components.

This is my webpack configuration:

**main.js**

```
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  stories: [],
  addons: [
    {
      name: '@storybook/addon-docs',
      options: {
        sourceLoaderOptions: null
      },
    },
    '@storybook/addon-essentials'
  ],
  webpackFinal: async (config, { configType }) => {
    config.optimization = {
      ...config.optimization,
      minimizer: [
        // exclude psdpdfkit-lib chunks since they are delivered optimized by the vendor
        new TerserPlugin({
          exclude: /pspdfkit-lib/,
        }),
      ],
    };
    return config;
  },
};
```

Here you can see what versions am I using.

**package.json**

```
...
    "@nrwl/cli": "14.1.7",
    "@nrwl/cypress": "14.1.7",
    "@nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx": "14.1.7",
    "@nrwl/jest": "14.1.7",
    "@nrwl/linter": "14.1.7",
    "@nrwl/nx-cloud": "latest",
    "@nrwl/storybook": "14.1.7",
    "@nrwl/workspace": "14.1.7",
    "@storybook/addon-a11y": "^6.4.22",
    "@storybook/addon-docs": "^6.4.22",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^6.4.22",
    "@storybook/angular": "^6.4.22",
    "@storybook/builder-webpack5": "^6.4.22",
    "@storybook/core-server": "^6.4.22",
    "@storybook/manager-webpack5": "^6.4.22",
...
```

This is my test story file and this is generated automatically when I set up Storybook.

**test.component.stories.ts**

```
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { moduleMetadata, Story, Meta } from '@storybook/angular';
import { TestComponent } from './test.component';
import { DataAccessModule } from '../../data-access/data-access.module';

export default {
  title: 'TestComponent/TestComponent',
  component: TestComponent,
  decorators: [
    moduleMetadata({
      declarations: [TestComponent],
      imports: [ MatButtonModule, DataAccessModule],
    }),
  ],
} as Meta<TestComponent>;

const Template: Story<TestComponent> = (args: TestComponent) => ({
  props: args,
});

export const Primary = Template.bind({});
Primary.args = {};
Primary.argTypes = {};
```

**Results:**

[image]

[image]

Any help appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: I have fixed this by removing the { docs: { inlineStories: true/false } } from the addParameters() configuration in preview.js.

Comment: I removed docs: { inlineStories: true/false } from preview.js, and it worked! thanks!!